# How to create a pymongo client in Django (using uwsgi)

Tags: django, pymongo, uwsgi

I am using Django with PostgreSQL, but I have some views that are using PyMongo to get and insert data into a MongoDB database. I would like to know where should I create the PyMongo client because for now it prints `UserWarning: MongoClient opened before fork. Create MongoClient only after forking. See PyMongo's documentation for details: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/faq.html#is-pymongo-fork-safe
 "MongoClient opened before fork. Create MongoClient only "`

I am using uwsgi and it forks when gets a request.

I tried to use the example from here: https://gist.github.com/josephmosby/4497f8a4f675170180ab

But I have the same error. The only difference is that I am getting `THE_MONGO_CLIENT` directly from `project/project/__init__.py` when I need it, instead of having a `get_mongo_db` method.

I also tried to put `gevent.monkey.patch_all()` in `project/project/__init__.py`, but it has the same error.